# MongoError: Cannot create collection users - database is in the process of being dropped

Tags: node.js, mongodb, unit-testing, tdd, jestjs

I have a REST API and I'm writing TDD for this project. My TDD is consisted of two parts: route and service. I chose to use **Jest**. I have a **MongoDB** database that I use for testing. When each test is completed, I reset my database using the `afterAll()` method. In this method, I run the `mongoose.connection.dropDatabase` function.

There is no error when I ran only one test file but when I run multiple test files, I get an error. The error message:

> MongoError: Cannot create collection auth-db.users - database is in
>   the process of being dropped.

I share sample codes with you:

`users.route.test.ts:`

https://gist.github.com/mksglu/8c4c4a3ddcb0e56782725d6457d97a0e

`users.service.test.ts:`

https://gist.github.com/mksglu/837202c1048687ad33b4d1dee01bd29c

When all my tests run, "`sometimes`" gives errors. I wrote the above error message. The reason for this error is that the reset process still continues. I can't solve this problem. I'd appreciate it if you could help.

Thanks.

Comment: Means what it says of course. You are clearly not waiting for a Promise/Callback to resolve which is dropping the database. You need to do that.

Comment: @NeilLunn,i know but how can i do that?

Comment: Well you have not included any code in the question at all. We don't read minds here, so you actually need to ["show us".](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). But honestly, *"waiting for a Promise/Callback to resolve"* is pretty self explanatory, and if you *"don't know how to do that"* we can probably best point you at existing answers which already show you how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://jestjs.io/docs/en/cli.html#runinband

What you are looking for is --runInBand command. Which makes jest to run serially instead of creating a worker pool of child processes that run tests

Answer (score 0):

For my e2e tests (using JEST, Mongoose and Nestjs), using --runInBand and awaiting for the connection.db.dropDatabase() didn't worked.

I was still getting **'database is in the process of being dropped'** whithin the next test case.

As an alternative, what I did was, instead of dropping the database, just clearing all collections:

```
const collections = await connection.db.listCollections().toArray().filter(val => val.name !== 'system.views');
for (const collection of collections) {
  const collectionInDb = connection.collection(collection.name);
  await collectionInDb.deleteMany({});
}
```